# Tracing the origin of a document.write / .appendChild

Tags: javascript, ajax, debugging

I have a a lot of JS tracking scripts running on my site. One of them is causing 404 errors by embedding a faulty script tag after the page has loaded like:

```
<script src="1234" />
<script src="%5Bobject%20DOMStringMap%5D" />
```

Is there an easy way to trace calls to the dom for any of these modifications ? Some of the js calls are using the timeout functions for defered executions ... so it's a real mess to step through in a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite it temporarily, throw an error and look at the stack trace: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/b5ayw/.

```
Element.prototype.appendChild = function() {
    try {
        throw new Error;
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e.stack);
    }
};
```

Comment: still does not do the trick for me :( ... i am also using head.js for defered script loading ... which also complicates things even more

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the [DOMNodeInserted](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMNodeInserted)-event, it is however not supported in all browsers.

Comment: That event *indicates* a change, but doesn't tell you where it originated from which is, what I think the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Try using *firebug* with *Firefox*

Comment: i tried to step through a lot of these tracking scripts in firebug - but since it's some > 1000 lines of code i was hoping to go after the modification events directly